# HP Pavilion g6 laptop backlight turns off at login screen

Tags: 11.10, backlight

I've seen posts like these but they all seem to mention the inability to get the brightness back up. I *can* turn the brightness back up with my keyboard, but it's an annoyance that I'd like to get rid of if at all possible.

Answer (score 2):

After new install with Ubuntu 11.10 in HP G6-1229 Laptop I had the same problem. This was the best solution for me

After the install the LCD was black after boot. What you need to do is edit `/etc/default/grub` with you facorite text editor, ie:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

And change the line

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

with

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor splash"`

Then update grub with

```
sudo update-grub
```

and restart the notebook.

Answer (score 1):

Use your Fn (function) key with F3 (brightness raiser) to restore brightness to your display.

Answer (score 0):

It's just at zero brightness. Increase the Brightness and it's all solved.

Answer (score 0):

On my `/etc/default/grub` file, the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor splash"
```

Did work perfect for me too, the only drawback i had to perform the first installation with no backlight. I'm using an hp (hp folio 13-1000) with the integrated intel chipset.